# Find - xargs, for every line open a new shell and execute a command and wait for user to exit that shell

Tags: bash, find, xargs, gnu, read

#### Following works

- **Task**: List all folders that contain file of iname `*AlbumArt*` that also contain iname `*cover*.jpg`, and for each of those folder list all jpg files with size

  ```
  find . -type f -iname '*AlbumArt*' -print0 | sort -z \
    | xargs -0 -I "{}" bash -c '
    find "$(dirname "${1}")" -maxdepth 1 -iname "*cover*.jpg" -print0' _ "{}" \; \
    | uniq -z | xargs -0 -I "{}" bash -c '
    ls -la "$(dirname "${1}")"/*.jpg;' _ "{}" \;
  ```

### What I actually want to do?

I want to list all folder that contain iname `*cover*.jpg` and iname`*AlbumArt*` and list the size of each image file in that folder and also open nautilus so that I can manually inspect those images in that folder (as I want to delete some extra files), this I want to do one folder at a time. So for each output of xargs I want to do `ls -la` and open nautilus and wait for nautilus to close so I added `nautilus "${1}";  read -r -p "Press any key to continue" Continue;` to above:

```
find . -type f -iname '*AlbumArt*' -print0 | sort -z \
  | xargs -0 -I "{}" bash -c '
  find "$(dirname "${1}")" -maxdepth 1 -iname "*cover*.jpg" -print0' _ "{}" \; \
  | uniq -z | xargs -0 -I "{}" bash -c '
  ls -la "$(dirname "${1}")"/*.jpg; nautilus "${1}"; read -r -p "Press any key to continue" Continue;' _ "{}" \;
```

This works but it won't stop for user input as per `read -r -p "Press any key to continue" Continue;` i.e. several windows of nautilus opens! But I want to open only one nautilus at a time so I want xargs to wait after each execution of the line.

What should I do to make xargs wait for user input after each line of execution?

Comment: In the directory tree in question, do you have `*cover*.jpg` files that are **not** in directories that contain `*AlbumArt*` files? If not, why bother with that condition; just look for the cover jpegs.

Comment: In the man pages of [`xargs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html), read about `-a file, --arg-file=file` and `-o, --open-tty`

Comment: @Kaz My assumption is that there are several directories which contain cover.jpg but not `*AlbumArt*` file. I wanted to list directories that contain both. Is there a better way to do that like an `&&` operator?

Answer (score 1):

Since that `read` command is in a shell invoked by `xargs`, its standard input is either `/dev/null` (with most xargs implementations) or the pipe that `xargs` reads from. To have it read from the terminal, redirect its standard input: `read … </dev/tty`.

---

I haven't reviewed your code. It looks complicated. It would be simpler, and probably not perceptibly slower, to just iterate over all directories.

```bash
shopt -s globstar nullglob nocaseglob
# Caveat: this matches symbolic links to directories. And in
# versions of bash prior to 5.0 traverses (some of) those symlinks.
for d in **/*/; do
  a=( "$d"/*albumart*  )
  c=( "$d"/*cover*.jpg )
  if (( ${#a[@]} > 0 && ${#c[@]} > 0} )); then
    ls -ld -- "$d"/*.jpg
    nautilus -- "${c[@]}"
    read -r -p "Press <Return> to continue" Continue
  fi
done
```

Comment: @aviro Ah, yes. Thank you.

Comment: Clarification: Does `**/*` recurses till the bottom of the directory tree? Does the mentioned caveat mean that it will follow any symbolic link in the directory tree?

Comment: @Porcupine `**/*` does not follow symlinks except in bash 4.0-4.2.x. Hopefully those old versions aren't in use anymore. (MacOS's ancient bash is too old to support `**` at all.) My caveat is that if `path/to/link` is a symlink to a directory, then it is matched by my code snippet, whereas the `find` commands wouldn't match it. But (apart from old bash) `path/to/link/subdir` isn't considered.